# Mostrar Senha digitada em dois campos clicando em apenas um ícone

Tags: javascript, html5, twitter-bootstrap

Tenho uma página para mudar a senha do usuário com dois campos um para a senha e outro para confirmar a senha. Gostaria de saber como faço para mostrar nos dois campos a senha digitada clicando em apenas um ícone, no código abaixo consigo apenas em um dos campos.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="card card-container" style="margin-top: 100px;">
            <!-- <img class="profile-img-card" src="//lh3.googleusercontent.com/-6V8xOA6M7BA/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/rzlHcD0KYwo/photo.jpg?sz=120" alt="" /> -->
            <div align="center" style="margin-top: 30px;">
            <th></th>
            <br><br><div style="color: rgb(104, 145, 162); font-size: 150%;">Mudar Senha</div>
            </div><br><div style="color: red; text-align: center">Alteração De Senha</div>
            <p id="profile-name" class="profile-name-card"></p>
            <form class="form-signin" method="POST" action="pass_user.php">
   <input type="hidden" name="usuario" value="<?php print $usuário = $_SESSION['usuarioId']; ?>" >
                <input type="password" id="inputPassword1" class="form-control" name="senha1" placeholder="Nova Senha" required autofocus><br>
                <input type="password" id="inputPassword2" name="senha2" class="form-control" placeholder="Confirme Nova Senha" required>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open " style="background:transparent;border:none;" onclick="mostrar()"></button>
                            </form>
                            <script>
                                function mostrar(){
                                    var tipo = document.getElementById("inputPassword1");
                                    if(tipo.type == "password"){
                                        tipo.type = "text";
                                    }else{
                                        tipo.type = "password";
                                    }
                                }
                            </script>
                <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block btn-signin" type="submit">Login</button>
</form><!-- /form -->
 
    <script>
    $('form').on('submit', function () {
        if ($('#inputPassword1').val() != $('#inputPassword2').val()) {
            alert('Senhas diferentes');
            return false;
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Você pegou esse elemento: `var tipo = document.getElementById("inputPassword1");` e trocou o tipo dele. Basta fazer o mesmo para o `#inputPassword2`, dentro da função `mostrar()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para mostrar a password nos dois ao mesmo tempo precisa apenas de apanhar o novo campo, e aplicar o `type` do primeiro:

```
var tipo2 = document.getElementById("inputPassword2");
tipo2.type = tipo.type; //aplica o tipo que ficou no primeiro campo
```

Veja o exemplo:

```js
function mostrar() {
  var tipo = document.getElementById("inputPassword1");
  var tipo2 = document.getElementById("inputPassword2");

  if (tipo.type == "password") {
    tipo.type = "text";
  } else {
    tipo.type = "password";
  }

  tipo2.type = tipo.type; //aplica o tipo que ficou no primeiro campo
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="card card-container" style="margin-top: 100px;">
  <!-- <img class="profile-img-card" src="//lh3.googleusercontent.com/-6V8xOA6M7BA/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/rzlHcD0KYwo/photo.jpg?sz=120" alt="" /> -->
  <div align="center" style="margin-top: 30px;">
    <th></th>
    <br><br>
    <div style="color: rgb(104, 145, 162); font-size: 150%;">Mudar Senha</div>
  </div><br>
  <div style="color: red; text-align: center">Alteração De Senha</div>
  <p id="profile-name" class="profile-name-card"></p>
  <form class="form-signin" method="POST" action="pass_user.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="usuario" value="<?php print $usuário = $_SESSION['usuarioId']; ?>">
    <input type="password" id="inputPassword1" class="form-control" name="senha1" placeholder="Nova Senha" required autofocus><br>
    <input type="password" id="inputPassword2" name="senha2" class="form-control" placeholder="Confirme Nova Senha" required>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open" style="background:transparent;border:none;" onclick="mostrar()"></button>
  </form>

  <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block btn-signin" type="submit">Login</button>
  </form>
  <!-- /form -->

  <script>
    $('form').on('submit', function() {
      if ($('#inputPassword1').val() != $('#inputPassword2').val()) {
        alert('Senhas diferentes');
        return false;
      }
    });
  </script>
```

Se quiser pode também transformar o seu `if` num ternário que fica mais curto e com a mesma legibilidade:

```
tipo.type = tipo.type == "password" ? "text" : "password";
```

**Edit**:

Para trocar também o icone, precisa de conseguir analisar o icone que está e trocar o que tem. Como os icones tem a ver com as classes aplicadas, pode utilizar as funções `contains`, `add` e `remove` de [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList).

Naturalmente que podia fazer com JQuery também, mas já que a primeira parte do código está feita em JS puro, mostro a parte do icone também em JS puro.

Implementação:

```js
function mostrar() {
  var tipo = document.getElementById("inputPassword1");
  var tipo2 = document.getElementById("inputPassword2");

  if (tipo.type == "password") {
    tipo.type = "text";
  } else {
    tipo.type = "password";
  }

  tipo2.type = tipo.type; //aplica o tipo que ficou no primeiro campo
  
  
  var botao = document.querySelector(".btn.btn-sm"); //obter o botão
  
  if (botao.classList.contains("glyphicon-eye-open")){ //se tem olho aberto
      botao.classList.remove("glyphicon-eye-open"); //remove classe olho aberto
      botao.classList.add("glyphicon-eye-close"); //coloca classe olho fechado
  }
  else { //senão
      botao.classList.remove("glyphicon-eye-close"); //remove classe olho fechado
      botao.classList.add("glyphicon-eye-open"); //coloca classe olho aberto
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="card card-container" style="margin-top: 100px;">
  <!-- <img class="profile-img-card" src="//lh3.googleusercontent.com/-6V8xOA6M7BA/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/rzlHcD0KYwo/photo.jpg?sz=120" alt="" /> -->
  <div align="center" style="margin-top: 30px;">
    <th></th>
    <br><br>
    <div style="color: rgb(104, 145, 162); font-size: 150%;">Mudar Senha</div>
  </div><br>
  <div style="color: red; text-align: center">Alteração De Senha</div>
  <p id="profile-name" class="profile-name-card"></p>
  <form class="form-signin" method="POST" action="pass_user.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="usuario" value="<?php print $usuário = $_SESSION['usuarioId']; ?>">
    <input type="password" id="inputPassword1" class="form-control" name="senha1" placeholder="Nova Senha" required autofocus><br>
    <input type="password" id="inputPassword2" name="senha2" class="form-control" placeholder="Confirme Nova Senha" required>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open" style="background:transparent;border:none;" onclick="mostrar()"></button>
  </form>

  <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block btn-signin" type="submit">Login</button>
  </form>
  <!-- /form -->

  <script>
    $('form').on('submit', function() {
      if ($('#inputPassword1').val() != $('#inputPassword2').val()) {
        alert('Senhas diferentes');
        return false;
      }
    });
  </script>
```

Comment: Só mais uma pergunta. Eu uso o ícone de olho aberto. Como faço pra quando o estiver visível o ícone mudar também?  Nesse usarei o ícone do boostrap de olho fechado.

Comment: @CarlosKhan Isso já é outra pergunta, mas na minha boa vontade posso ajudar um pouco ai também. Qual é o icone do bootstrap para o olho fechado ?

Comment: No caso o botão mudaria 

de: 
<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open " style="background:transparent;border:none;" onclick="mostrar()"></button>

Para:

<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm glyphicon glyphicon-eye-close " style="background:transparent;border:none;" onclick="mostrar()"></button>

Comment: @CarlosKhan Já editei a resposta, para também contemplar a parte do icone, incluindo os comentários necessários para que a consiga perceber.

Comment: Realmente essa parte foi mais por capricho. Obrigado pela explicação e solução. Mto obrigado mesmo!